# Apache Conf files: If Hostname=="Web4" Then Use This IP for VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2

I am getting ready to do a "spring cleaning" on the web heads at work. I would really like to put my config files into a git repo, and use the same config files for all the web heads. This is a problem for the sites that are on port 443.

Is there anyway to do an if statement or something like that inside the conf file itself? I am trying to avoid writing a script to generate the conf files.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IfDefine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine) - Encloses directives that will be processed only if a test is true at startup.

Adjust your Apache startup script to define any parameters you need with `-D` option.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! I just found that for Redhat, you can place variables in /etc/sysconfig/httpd that can be accessed ${VARNAME}